# How to estimate the size of balanced biclique in random bipartite graph?

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, graph-theory

We have a random bipartite graph $G=(V,U,E)$ and $|V|=|U|=n$, in which any vertex pair $<v,u>$ ($v\in V$,$u\in U$) exists an edge with probability $p$. A balanced bipartite complete graph is a biclique $G(X,Y,E)$ that $|X|=|Y|$ and $E=X\times Y$ . So, does somebody have an idea about how to estimate the distribution of maximum size of balanced biclique?

Comment: Edge exists with which probability?

Comment: Looks like standard second-moment method.

Comment: @joey: Perhaps better ask this question on http://math.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @FedorPetrov , sorry,  probability $0<p<1$